# Acessar linha e coluna especifica de uma list C#

Tags: c#, lista

Como faço uma list multidimensional, e que eu possa adicionar elementos tipo assim:

```
List<List<String>> listaMultidimensional = new List<List<string>>();

listaMultidimensional[0][0].Add ("maca");
listaMultidimensional[0][1].Add ("banana");
listaMultidimensional[1][3].Add ("limão");
```

O que consigo fazer é:

```
listaMultidimensional[0].Add("maca");
```

Isso seria adicionar "maca" na primeira linha na primeira coluna, mas como faço para adicionar "maca" na segunda coluna([0][1]) por exemplo? E depois como faria para acessar o dado de uma linha e coluna especifica dessa lista?

Comment: Nesse caso recomendo que você use DataTable.

Comment: Isso não faz muito sentido, tente melhorar sua pergunta, mostrar o que está tentando fazer, mostrar onde quer chegar.

Comment: Eu entendi oque ele quis dizer, tira o pendente.

Comment: Dá para entender sim, é simples o que perguntei, não creio que precisaria de um exemplo.

Comment: Com a resposta aceita fica mais evidente que não está claro. A pergunta fala em lista, a resposta fala em `DataTable`, são coisas tão distintas que só por adivinhação seria possível responder isso. Pra falar a verdade eu acho que a resposta nem reponde o que ele queria de fato, como ele ainda está aprendendo ele se apegou ao que foi postado. A pergunta em conjunto com a resposta vai trazer dificuldades para uma pessoa que está aprendendo que vai achar que lista e `DataTable` é tudo a mesma coisa.

Comment: Eu também entendi sua pergunta e responderia com mais uma opção se ela não tivesse sido fechada :-/ O DataTable é uma completa estrutura de objetos, especialmente útil para permitir edição de dados em controles do usuário e mandar estas alterações de volta para a base de dados, pois suas linhas guardam versões dos dados, ele suporta constraints, relacionamentos com outros datatables, notifica eventos de edição, etc. Outra opção de solução seria você fazer tua própria estrutura de dados, com um recurso de busca, algo mais simples que o DataTable.

Comment: Eu queria inicialmente usar a lista, mas seria mais complicado usando a lista, se existe uma maneira melhor não vejo porque não usar. Alguém vindo procurar fazer isso por uma lista, vai encontrar o tópico e saber que com DataTable seria melhor opção nesse caso.

Comment: E como seria essa outra opção?

Comment: @MoribundoChat Com a pergunta fechada não dá para responder.

Comment: ta aberta agora.

Comment: @MoribundoChat Não se trata de você ter marcado uma resposta como aceita ou não :D Eu responderia mesmo você já tendo aceitado uma. O problema é que sua pergunta foi fechada pelo moderador do site. Talvez se você fizer uma edição ela pode ser reaberta. Experimente editar a pergunta e mencionar o nome das colunas ("nome, cor, tipo...") ou sei lá... Não sei o que o moderador não entendeu.

Comment: Me fale por mp, aqui tem msg privada? nem vi ainda kkkkk Se existe outra maneira, quero aprender também. Sempre é bom aprender de várias formas a resolver um mesmo problema.

Comment: @MoribundoChat, eu usaria um forma completamente diferente. Criaria uma classe com os atributos que você precisa. Daí é só criar um List desta classe e adicionar as opções que você precisa. Dai pra recuperar as posições específicas tem diversas formas, mas eu usaria expressoes lambda. Com a pergunta fechada não dá pra apresentar o exemplo. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo muito bom aqui com DataTable:

// Criando a tabela.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("Alimentos");

// Adicionando as colunas e seus respectivos tipos de dados.
table.Columns.Add("Nome").DataType = typeof(string);
table.Columns.Add("Cor").DataType = typeof(string);
table.Columns.Add("Tipo").DataType = typeof(string);
table.Columns.Add("Cor da folha").DataType = typeof(string);
table.Columns.Add("Aparência").DataType = typeof(string);
table.Columns.Add("Classificação").DataType = typeof(string);

// Adicionando as linhas.
table.Rows.Add("maca", "vermelha", "fruta", "verde", "bonita", "natural");

//Printando as linhas.
for(int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if((table.Rows[i][0] as string).Contains("maca")) // Use "as string" pois o table.Rows[i][0] retorna um objeto, e você sabe que o objeto é uma string.
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nome: " + table.Rows[i][0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Cor: " + table.Rows[i][1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Tipo: " + table.Rows[i][2]);
        Console.WriteLine("Cor da folha: " + table.Rows[i][3]);
        Console.WriteLine("Aparência: " + table.Rows[i][4]);
        Console.WriteLine("Classificação: " + table.Rows[i][5]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Opa, valeu, vou estudar aqui agora o DataTable, nunca utilizei, mas acredito que seja isso mesmo que preciso.

Comment: O DataTable não possui Contains, existe algo parecido para procurar uma valor nas tabelas? algo tipo contains que procuro macaa, e ele encontra maca.

Comment: Tem sim, vou editar ok?

Comment: Prontinho, se você não souber direito pra quê serve as string, não se preocupe, com o tempo provavelmente vai entender.

Comment: Olha, dessa vez você deixou algumas informações faltando, eu só entendi o seu comentário pois vi sua outra postagem, da uma melhorada depois ok?

Comment: Agradeço novamente, você não entendeu bem o comentário ou a pergunta? Vou tentar melhorar aqui.